# navigateTo Proplem In Nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

I encountered a problem that I could not move between pages unless I refreshed the page

I used code in this way

```html
<div class=" fixed bottom-0   bg-zinc-950/30 backdrop-blur-lg h-16 w-screen flex justify-around text-black items-center">
  <NuxtLink v-for="link in links" :key="link.id"  :to="link.path">
    <NuxtImg v-if="link.img" class="w-11" :src="link.img" />
    <Icon v-else size="30" :name="link.icon" />
  </NuxtLink>
</div>
```

This is the script code

```
const links = [ { id: 1, name: "Account", path: "/account", icon: "material-symbols:settings-rounded", isActive: false, }, { id: 3, name: "Home", path: "/", img: "/Home.png", isActive: false, }, { id: 5, name: "Orders", path: "/orders", icon: "material-symbols:order-approve-rounded", isActive: false, }, ];
```

I used two methods

1. navigateTo
2. to attribute

The problem is still not solved

Comment: Can you provide more of your example project? This isn't a lot to go off of. Also, are there any errors in your console?